# How to change the position of the popup

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a table with three columns and in the last one, I have a word that when clicked it will show a popup directly above the word.
My problem is that the popup always shows on the same spot, right above the word on the first row, on the third column. So if on row number 5 I click on the word the popup will appear as if the word on row number 1 was clicked.
I want it to show directly above the word on the respective row it was clicked.

```js
function openPopup() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
#table {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 8px auto 0px;
}

#table td,
#table th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

#table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

#table th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
}

.popup {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.popup .popuptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}

.popup .popuptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.popup .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<table width='100%' id='table'>
  <tr>
    <th><b>Coluna1:</b></th>
    <th><b>Coluna2:</b></th>
    <th><b>Coluna3:</b></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Word1</td>
    <td>Text1</td>
    <td>
      <center>
        <div class='popup' onclick='openPopup()'>Show1
          <span class='popuptext' id='myPopup'>Popup text...</span>
        </div>
      </center>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Word2</td>
    <td>Text2</td>
    <td>
      <center>
        <div class='popup' onclick='openPopup()'>Show2
          <span class='popuptext' id='myPopup'>Popup text...</span>
        </div>
      </center>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Word3</td>
    <td>Text3</td>
    <td>
      <center>
        <div class='popup' onclick='openPopup()'>Show3
          <span class='popuptext' id='myPopup'>Popup text...</span>
        </div>
      </center>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How do I change my code to make this happen?

Comment: `getElementById` will return the first element it finds, which means every onclick will toggle the first `myPopup` element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you use the same identifier, so javascript accesses the first one it finds and adds the class.

The solution that occurs to me is to specify a unique id per element and pass this to the javascript method.

HTML

```
<td>
  <center>
    <div class='popup' onclick='openPopup(this)'>Show1 
      <!-- We pass "this" to openPopup -->
      <span class='popuptext' id='myPopup1'>Popup text...</span>
    </div>
  </center>
</td>
```

JS

```
function openPopup(element) { 
  // We receive the item and access its id
  let myChildElementId = element.childNodes[1].id;
  let popup = document.getElementById(myChildElementId);

  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

Now every time you launch the function the element is passed with its unique id.

[Here's the full example.](https://codepen.io/angabar/pen/QWyOqYv)

Comment: Instead of the word "Show1" I wanted to put an image: <img src='../img/view.jpg' width=30 height=25> but when I change, it stops working. How can I make it work with an image?

Comment: I have modified the example so that you see it with images, can you tell me if it is ok?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't explain myself well, I meant that instead of the word "Show1" I want: <div class='popup' onclick='openPopup(this)'><img src='../img/view.jpg' width=30 height=25>
          <span class='popuptext' id='myPopup1'>Popup text...</span>
        </div>
That way, I click on the image and the popup text appears.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try `querySelectorAll("#myPopup")` since this would select all of your span elements compared to `getElementByID("myPopup")`.

If that doesn't work, I would try giving them a unique id and working from there, but that would take more work.

Good luck!